# Insert into database button code not working unsure how to fix it

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have tried to fix it but it wont take the three words i try to insert. it says error

> "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0."

here is the button code

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionOne");
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test.lifestyle(animal_food,animal_hobbies,animal_sport) values('" + this.food_txt.Text + "','" + this.hobby_txt.Text + "','" + sport_txt.Text + "');");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();


    }
```

The ConnectionOne is the name of the connection i have made with the data base

Comment: are you sure that your connection string is valid?

Comment: the value of the texts are text boxes which people can insert data into

Comment: The text boxes could contain SQL, making the statement invalid

Comment: you should be selecting your database in your connection string not in your sql command (i.e. `test.`)

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect you have a variable as `ConnectionOne` and this saves your string.

In such a case, you need to use it as;

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionOne);
```

But more important, you should always use [paramterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concateanations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` instead of calling `.Close()` method manually.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionOne))
     using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
     {
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO test.lifestyle(animal_food,animal_hobbies,animal_sport) 
                            values(@food, @hobbies, @sport)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@food", this.food_txt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobbies", this.hobby_txt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sport", sport_txt.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```